# reading file error in c language

Tags: c, file

I have write a code for read from file , which has the following contant : 
`76 -1217454080  77 -1217458176  78 -1217462272` by this code :

```
FILE* fp;
        if((fp = fopen("test" , "r")) < 0 )
            printf("ERROR in FILE \n") ;
        int old_fp = fp ;
        int shm , key ;
        fp = fscanf(fp , " %d%d" , &key , &shm) ;
        if(fp < 0)
            printf("ERROR in fscanf \n ");
        printf("%d , %d \n " , key , shm) ;
        while( fp != EOF)
        {
            if(key == 5)
                break ;

            fp = fscanf(fp , "%d" , &key) ;
            fp = fscanf(fp , "%d" , &shm) ;
            printf("%d , %d\n" , key , shm) ;
        }
```

but when reach the loop (enter the loop) the program give me `segmentation fault` , so i have tried ny this code (which is make first statement read 4 integers at the same time ) and it works for reading 4 integers at same time , but it again when it enter the loop , and it want to do `fscanf` , the program crash !

```
 FILE* fp;
            if((fp = fopen("test" , "r")) < 0 )
                printf("ERROR in FILE \n") ;
            int old_fp = fp ;
            int shm , key ;
                    int ss , kk ;
            fp = fscanf(fp , "%d%d%d%d" , &key , &shm,&ss,&kk) ;
            printf("the  result is %d %d " , ss , kk );
            if(fp < 0)
                printf("ERROR in fscanf \n ");
            printf("%d , %d \n " , key , shm) ;
            while( fp != EOF)
            {
                if(key == 5 )
                    break ;
    // it's crash here
                fp = fscanf(fp , "%d" , &key) ;
                fp = fscanf(fp , "%d" , &shm) ;
                printf("%d , %d \n " , key , shm) ;
            }
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to use `fp` for two entirely different purposes at the same time ???

Comment: There are a lot of problems with the code you have. fp is a FILE pointer, not an integer. You overwrite fp with the return from the first fscanf that you have (actually all of them). You get the segfault in the loop because fscanf tries to dereference fp, which does not point to a valid memory location. This is a bad question. RTFM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fp = fscanf(fp , "%d" , &key);
```

You are destroying your fp!
`fscanf` returns an `int` and fp is of type `FILE*`.